# HTC One M8 boot into recovery mode after updating to Android 6.0

Tags: updates, recovery-mode, stock-android, 6.0-marshmallow, htc-one-m8

I am not an Android expert so I didn't try any root, flash, custom ROMs or custom recovery modes. All I did was approving to update my HTC One M8 to Android 6.0. After downloading updates and installation finish, my device booted into stock recovery mode with the message:

[image: android recovery]

I've tried wiping cache and factory reset several times with no success.

P.S: I don't have SD card on my device and I tried booting with one SD card inserted and the same message show up.

Comment: Same issue reported on [AndroidCentral](http://forums.androidcentral.com/htc-one-m8/634921-htc-one-m8-stuck-android-recovery-after-failed-update-how-can-i-fix.html#post4963342), try if it fixes the issue.